# linq - list of string - order by letter only, and then by numbers

Tags: c#, linq

For example :

this array:

```
a 2
a 10
a
```

should be after sort :

```
a
a 2
a 10
```

I try this, but it doesn't not work: the order is wrong.

```
 ... 
.OrderBy(s => s.name)
.ThenBy(s => {
   var stringNumber = Regex.Match(s.name, @"\d+").Value;

   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringNumber) 
     ? 0 
     : int.Parse(stringNumber);
 });
```

Comment: What does "is not work" mean exactly? And do your `name`s always look like this: single character-space-number?

Comment: what is ur output

Comment: The problem is that you at first sort by the **whole string**, so `ThenBy` has no effect anymore, you need to `OrderBy` the letter only, `ThenBy` the number only.

Comment: Select into an anonymous type that splits the string into string and int? Then order by accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said "letter" I assume you want to only sort by the **first** character, then by the number.

So don't `OrderBy` the *whole* string, but by the letter only:

```
var result = list
          .OrderBy(s => s.FirstOrDefault()) // only first character
          .ThenBy(s =>
             {
                var stringNumber = Regex.Match(s.name, @"\d+").Value;
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringNumber) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringNumber);
             })
```

Your code sorted by the *whole* string at first, so `ThenBy` had no effect anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest extracting criterium explicitly: `name` and `number` groups in the regular expression:

```
  var list = new List<string>() {
    "a",
    "a 4",
    "b 1",
    "a 2",
    "a 11"
  };

  var result = list
    .Select(item => new {
         value = item,
         match = Regex.Match(item, @"^(?<name>.*?)\s*(?<number>[0-9]*)$"), 
       })
    .OrderBy(item => item.match.Groups["name"].Value)
    .ThenBy(item => item.match.Groups["number"].Value.Length)
    .ThenBy(item => item.match.Groups["number"].Value)
    .Select(item => item.value);
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
a
a 2
a 4
a 11
b 1
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the new tuple types can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that;

```
        var list = new List<string>()
        {
            "a ",
            "a 4",
            "b 1",
            "a 2"
        };

        int value = 0;

        list = list
          .Select(x => new {
             WholeString = x,
             StringPart = x.Split(' ')[0],
             IntPart = int.TryParse(x.Split(' ')[1], out value) ? value : 0
            })
          .OrderBy(x => x.StringPart)
          .ThenBy(x => x.IntPart)
          .Select(x => x.WholeString)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = new[] {"a 2", "a 10", "a"};

var sorted = test.OrderBy(s => new string(s.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray())).ThenBy(s =>
{
    var stringNumber = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value;
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringNumber) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringNumber);
});
```

This should sort by letters first, then by numbers.